# Correctly importing CSV File into Neo4j database

Tags: csv, import, neo4j

I am currently trying to import a csv file into neo4j.
Now for example lets see the following file:

```
node1,node2
   value1,value2
   value2,value3
   value1,value2
```

Now what I am trying is to import those lines so that
nodes 1 and 2 will be connected, while identical nodes only exist once.
So I guess I will need to do the MERGE command which seems to work with 
the following CQL Request:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///test_text.csv" AS line 
   MERGE (u :word { value: line.node1 }) 
   MERGE (h :word { value: line.node2 }) 
   MERGE (u)-[t :digram]->(h)
```

Now I want to achieve, that connections between 2 nodes, which occur
multiple times in my csv file (like value1 to value 2 in the example above)
are represented by an attribute "count" in the corresponding connection.
So the connection between value1 and value2 has a attribute count=2.

I have tried to do that by appending the following line:

```
ON MERGE SET t.count = t.count + 1 ON CREATE SET t.count = 1
```

But that throws a syntax error. I am kind of lost at the moment and I am hoping
you guys could help.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Just a small error here, it's `ON MATCH SET`, not `ON MERGE SET`.

Comment: Well... im feeling pretty stupid now, but it perfectly worked :D So thank you very much.